# How to check to see if time has milliseconds as part of it

Tags: go

I have this time format stored in my database:

`2020-06-04T13:54:00.000Z`

Is there an easy way in Go to get just the milliseconds part of this time, which would be the `.000` part of the time?  I know I could probably do a regex to get it, but I am looking for an easier way to do this other than a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your title, to check if the time has milliseconds:

```
func timeHasMs(t time.Time) bool {
    return t.Sub(t.Round(time.Millisecond)) != 0
}
```

To answer the body of your question, and get just the MS:

```
func msOnly(t time.Time) time.Duration {
    return t.Sub(t.Round(time.Millisecond))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get milliseconds part only, here `t` is `time.Time`

```
ms := t.Nanosecond() / int(time.Millisecond)
```

If time in string you can parse into `time.Time` this way

```
t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z", "2020-06-04T13:54:00.450Z")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```